# Passing values between exported and non-exported part of script

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How to pass values between exported part of a script and non-exported one?

The construction looks like this:

```
<script>
// PART 1:
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js';

EventBus.$on('value-received', value => {
    this.receivedValue = value;
});

// PART 2:
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            receivedValue: ''
        }
    },
    watch: {...},
    methods: {...}
}
</script>
```

How can I get the `value` assigned to `receivedValue` variable and made usable by Vue methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `EventBus.$on` call uses an arrow function, the `this` it references is the `this` in scope at the time of the `EventBus` call.

If you are okay with all instances of your event having the same `receivedValue`, you could redirect the values received to an object in the scope of your file:

```
var shared = { receivedValue: '' };
EventBus.$on('value-received', value => {
    shared.receivedValue = value;
});

export default {
    data() { return shared; }
    watch: ...,
    methods: ....
}
```

Vue.js will register a handler to react on changes to the object you returned, ie. `shared`.

If for some reason you want a separate event stream per instance of your component, you need to create a new object inside the `data()` function and have your event bus update the new object directly.